# Jquery function to detect cookies and set focus

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have an asp.net login control and I have implemented the user name to be remembered using cookies. How can I use Jquery(javascript) function to detect cookies and set the focus on the password field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple cookies plugin for jquery:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
var userCookie = $.cookie("userName");
if(userCookie){
    // userName cookie exists
    $("#username").val(userCookie)
}
```

And focusing on the password field is as simple as

```
$("#password").focus()
```